# Combining views slideshow and views gallery on single page

Tags: views, javascript, media

I have a views Slideshow on one page. I also have a views Gallery on another page. I want the views gallery to appear below the views slideshow on a single page. Please could anyone help me out. I have been trying a lot, but I'm unable to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

- create a copy of one of the views as a BLOCK instead of a page
- under block configuration (admin/structure/blocks) for that view, limit it by page to ONLY show for the view still set as a page, and place it in the content or content bottom region

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module.
This module allows you to create partitions in a page & place content (such as Views or blocks or menus) within the desired partitions.

**!Note:**
Make sure you specify different Pager ID (Edit View > Page in middle column of the Edit view page > Pager settings where you specify number of links to show, previous & next options, etc) for each of the views.